# Legendre's Complete Elliptic Integral of the 1st Kind - Calculating the argument

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions, legendre-functions

Given the definition of the complete elliptic integral of the 1st kind ([see this link here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html)), I am interested in finding a particular value of $k$ such that

$$K(k) \equiv \int_0^1\dfrac{\operatorname{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-k^2t^2}} =  d/2, $$

where $d$ is a known positive constant.

I can numerically find this value of $k$ using Mathematica for various values of $d$. However, I would like to know if it is possible to obtain a general solution for $k$ given some constant $d$; essentially inverting this relation. I have little experience with these elliptic functions; regardless I am not certain how I would begin to approach solving this implicit equation in general.

My instinct suggests that since this definition exists, it may not be possible...

Any ideas/solutions welcome!

Comment: Look up the Jacobi elliptic functions. They are the inverses of the elliptic integrals.

Comment: Dear @Gary - thank you for your reply. I'm actually using these integral in the context of Jacobi elliptic functions! I'm attempting to find analytic expressions for the first two zeroes of the function - one is at 0 and the other at $2K$. My original ODE problem has a general solution in JacobiSN, and the boundary conditions demand for zeroes at say 0 and $d$. I believe that the value of $k$ takes me towards the hyperbolic limit - different values of $k$ will 'tune' the value of the first zero.